# ScrollFire Materialize reveal List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, materialize

Hi i am looking for a possible solution for the following problem.

I am building a website and i have a table which has many many rows.
I am using materialize (but if there is another plugin that can do it i am open for it).

Materialize uses this

```
 var options = [
  {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 50, callback: function(el) {
    Materialize.toast("This is our ScrollFire Demo!", 1500 );
  } },
  {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 205, callback: function(el) {
    Materialize.toast("Please continue scrolling!", 1500 );
  } },
  {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 400, callback: function(el) {
    Materialize.showStaggeredList($(el));
  } },
  {selector: '#image-test', offset: 500, callback: function(el) {
    Materialize.fadeInImage($(el));
  } }
];
Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

But how to implement it on table rows?

I would simply like to hide most of the rows but get visible the more the user scrolls down.

Is this possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of scroll i made a button to show more using javascript and jquery here is the function

```
$.fn.RowReveal = function(RowsToShow, numMore) {

var numShown = RowsToShow;
var numMore = numMore;

var $table = $(this).find('tbody');
var numRows = $table.find('tr').length;

var btn_id = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)+numRows;

// Hide rows and add clickable div
$table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
    .after('<tbody id="more-'+btn_id+'"><tr><td colspan="' +
        $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show More</div></tbody></td></tr>');

$('#more-'+btn_id).click(function () {
    numShown = numShown + numMore;
    if (numShown >= numRows) {
        $('#more-'+btn_id).remove();
    }
    if (numRows - numShown < numMore) {
        $('#more-'+btn_id+' span').html(numRows - numShown);
    }
    $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').fadeIn();
});
```

}